# Powers of Non-i.i.d. Random Matrices

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, reference-request, random-matrices

Suppose there is some Random Matrix $A$ which exists in $\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$. Each element in $A$ has a different $\mu$ and $\sigma$. However, all elements are independent of eachother.

$A$ is a [Ginibre ensemble](https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.2986) in that it is non-Hermitian. Furthermore, the eigenvalues of $A$ are mostly real but some are imaginary.

What are the distributions of $A^M$ where $M$ is a natural number?

So far, I have done numerical experiments by using [expressions for the distributions of eigenvalues (eq 2.15)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.07903.pdf) and the $U$ and $V$ matrices from the means of $A$.
I approximated the distribution of $A = U \Sigma V^T$ where all randomness is contained inside $\Sigma$ and $U$ and $V$ are fixed. Then I tried to recreate the distribution of $A$ by drawing samples from the distribution for $\Sigma$ and carrying out the matrix products. However, the distributions from recreating $A$ from sampling from the eigenvalue pdfs were not similar to the original distributions of $A$. Any information or resources is appreciated.

Comment: If $A = U \Sigma V^T$ with $U \ne V$ and $\Sigma$ is invertible, then $A^2 = U \Sigma V^T U \Sigma V^T \ne U \Sigma^2 V^T$.

Comment: Thank you. I will update my post with the results of a more simple numeric experiment which does not use my previously incorrect equality.